# need of classes though we have structures in c++

Tags: c++

I am able to do anything with structure that I can do with classes.give  the exact situation that I cant use structures and have to use only classes

Answer (score 4):

That’s correct, they are strictly redundant. The reason for the existence of both classes and structs is purely historical.

Comment: "purely historical" makes it sound like things would definitely be done differently if starting afresh, which is not necessarily the case at all - I bet a lot of C++ programmers like having both available.  While there's no particular functional need for both, there's some benefit in code concision, and arguably in implications that the choice might carry within a specific code base (though that's not necessarily a good practice).

Comment: @TonyD It’s hard to argue about something else’s internal state of mind. That said, yes, I do think that this would definitely be done differently today (and we can see this in other attempts at doing something similar to C++, such as D, Go and Rust).

Answer (score 4):

There are two different constructs: struct and class, in a class, members are private by default, whereas in struct, members are public by default. That's all. They can be used either way according to convenience.

Comment: There's also nasty compiler mode where it moans and groans if you forward declare a class and it turns out to be a struct. Not all compiler do it though.

Comment: Not just "members are private" - bases too.  @berkus: which is just one of the reasons for client code not to forward declare library content... the library should provide a forward declaration header if useful (e.g. `<iosfwd>`)

Comment: @TonyD It also works the same if you forward declare a class in YOUR OWN library. Bases access is specified after the colon, default one would differ, but you can override.

Answer (score 2):

In Short:

only difference between `class` and `struct` in c++ is that `structs` have default `public` members and bases and classes have default `private` members and bases.

Both can use `inheritance`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such case. Structures are classes where members are public by default.